# Python: wget randomly prints "-1 / unknown"

Tags: python, command-line, wget

I have a python script with a few loops and every now and then python prints this:

```
-1 / unknown
```

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Also this only happens when I run my script through windows command prompt or through a windows batch file, but not if I run it through PyCharm (a python IDE)

```
import wget

def fetch_page(url):
    wget.download(url, out='cache/page')
    page_file = open('cache/page', 'r', encoding='utf8')
    page = page_file.read()
    page_file.close()
    return page

fetch_page('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
```

Comment: You need to upload the code, so that one can fix the bug.

Comment: Relevant code needs to be in the question. Links could end up broken and are generally avoided on SO except to expand on a particular topic or focal area. .

Comment: Does it still print the unexpected message if you remove the `os.system('cls')` call?

Comment: @Kevin yes, thats just to clear the console so it doesn't get spammed with text, I've already tried removing it but that doesn't help.

Comment: @Kevin It seems like if I remove the os.system('cls') call it prints "-1 / unknown" just once at the start of the program, but without it it prints it once at startup and the everytime I call os.system('cls')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wget.download() needs a third argument for a progress bar which I left out.

Just add `bar=None` to `wget.download(url, out='cache/page')`:

```
wget.download(url, out='cache/page', bar=None)
```